# Update foreign key convention in EF4

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I've got a EF code first database.

I've got a couple of entities:

- customer and
- orders

where Orders references Customer

IE

```
public class Orders
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public Customer Customer {get; set}
    //snip...
}
```

This generated a DB with two tables

- Customer
- Orders

where Orders has a field **Customer_id** I need to have this field renamed to **CustomerId**.

I know I can map it, but I'd like this to be a convention.

I've looked at this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.conventions%28v=vs.103%29.aspx but I'm not clear on what these conventions all mean.

I'm using SqlServer 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Customer_id is generated by EF convention.

You have to declare a foreign key and use data annotation to associate it.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class Orders
{
    public Guid Id {get; set;}
    public Guid CustomerId  {get; set;}
    [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public Customer Customer {get; set}
    //snip...
}
```

Comment: hrm... I was really hoping this wasn't the case.